# Add a triangle shape after an element using tailwind in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, tailwind-css

I am trying to recreate this design for the navbar [image: navbar]

But I can't figure out a proper way to add the triangle shape.

What I have now: [image]

```
<!-- Navbar Logo Space  -->
<div>
    <div id="navbar-logo" class="z-0 inset-1.5 absolute bg-light-green w-1/4 h-24">
      <div class="hidden md:flex flex items-center space-x-1">
          <!-- logo  -->
          <a href="#" class = "py-5 px-2" >LOGO</a>

          <!-- title  -->
          <a href="#" class = "py-5 px-2">PLACEHOLDER</a>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I can add a triangle using this:

```
#navbar-logo::after {
    content: '';

    background: #06C982;
    
    position: absolute;
    
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    
    left: 27em;
    
    width: 10em;;
    
    height: 99%;
    
    transform: skewX(-38deg);
}
```

But its fixed and its causing issues with responsiveness.

Is there an efficient way I could do this? Possibly with tailwind.

Comment: Does it need to be 38deg? Can be done but simpler with 45deg.

Comment: No, I think 45deg would look fine as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with [CSS `clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).  There are generators online that can do this for you, but here's a snippet that should work while being responsive:

```css
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 80% 100%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

To change the angle, simply change the `80%` value in the snippet.  I do highly recommend learning clip-path though, it's a very helpful tool for unique CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple example (CSS) of adding an equilateral triangle after an element.

```css
#navbar-logo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow;
  visible;
  background: #06C982;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#navbar-logo::after {
  content: '';
  background: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<!-- Navbar Logo Space  -->
<div>
  <div id="navbar-logo">
    <div>
      <!-- logo  -->
      <a href="#">LOGO</a>

      <!-- title  -->
      <a href="#">PLACEHOLDER</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

It uses clip-path to form the triangle but note it makes sure that the height and width are equal so it's always a triangle with 45deg.

The problem with using a polygon clip-path on the whole actual element is that the angle will end up varying depending on the dimensions of the element, so it won't be responsive in that sense.